# Is there any way let SSMS remember the Save or Save As folder?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Anytime I create a new script and click Save, SSMS 'Save File As' dialog defaults to folder C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio, and offers to save my file to there. It takes 3-8 clicks and at least 5 seconds to browse the folder I would like to really save my script.

Within a time range when I working on a project I usually would like to save my files to the very same folder, which is obviously other than this default in my profile. Other programs, like Word, Browsers already invented this convenient thing, and can remember what was the last Save As folder, or at least use global (common) Windows Save File dialog remembered path.

I hate to  complaining but **this is a real productivity killer**. (One developer should invest *once* 5 minutes (including unit tests) in Redmond, and say 10 000 developers can spare 1 minutes *per day*. Sounds a good deal.)

Well it's 2015, and SSMS v14. Is this very basic UX implemented in SSMS and I am just missing something? I am kinda hoping in the latter that's why this question...

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/595-library-set-save-folder.html

Comment: Use Recent Places/or make custom library as link above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of SQL Server Projects?

You can create projects in SSMS , Which includes your queries , connection strings and many other things.

In SSMS go to File -->  New --> Project.

[image]

Create a Project ( you have to give a folder name a location), you have to do this only the very first time.

[image]

Once a project has been created then creating new scripts is as simple as right clicking on the `Query` folder in the Solution Explorer and naming the file, it will save all the files in the Queries folder in that project.

[image]